# Change body bgcolor when hovering over ul li. CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to change the background color of the body when hovering over ul li in css.

Comment: With CSS? No you can not change a parent from a child. You can do it with JavaScript.

Comment: I would search: hover event JS. Than I would add that event on my UL LI. Than I would google: how to target body element. Than I would google how to change element class . Three lines of simple code. What have you tried so far? What was your best attempt?

Comment: @Matthew not going to help

Answer (score -2):

Pure CSS experiment:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tymek/yrKRX/

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
}

#bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    widht: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #EEE;
}

#trigger {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 136px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -68px 0 0 -100px;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 2;
}

/* KEY */
#trigger:hover ~ #bg {
    background: #EE0;
}​
```

```html
<div id="trigger"></div>
<div id="bg"></div>
```